# Как вставить заголовок popup окна в скрытое поле Contact Form 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, frontend, contact-form7

Наверное, начну с того, что в программировании я понимаю чуть-чуть больше, чем ничего, поэтому прошу отнестись с пониманием и по возможности отвечать попроще)

В общем, делаю сайт на Wordpress + Elementor + Elementor Addon Elements, в котором использую элемент EAE – Modal Popup, с помощью которого создаю много popup окон с уникальными заголовками, а внутри использую предварительно сохраненный шаблон блока Elementor, вместе с контактной формой Contact Form 7.

Грубо говоря, на странице есть много кнопок, по клику по которым открываются popup окна с различными заголовками, но одним и тем же содержимым (с одной и той же контактной формой).

Задача в том, чтобы при открытии popup окна его заголовок копировался в скрытое поле, например `[dynamichidden dynamichidden-popupTitle id:hiddenFieldWithPopupTitle]` Contact Form 7.

Методом проб и ошибок удалось написать код:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function funonload(){
document.getElementById('hiddenFieldWithPopupTitle').innerText = document.querySelector("div > div.eae-modal-title.mfp-title").innerText;
}
window.onload = funonload;
</script>
```

Этот код я пытался вставлять как в шаблоне под контактной формой в элементе «простой HTML код», так и в самом редакторе Contact Form 7, но к сожалению, он вставляет оглавления только одного popup окна, которое открывается по первой кнопке на сайте и то только в поле типа textarea (`[textarea your_message2 id:hiddenFieldWithPopupTitle]`), а с полями типа dynamichidden не работает.

Собственно, сам вопрос: как сделать чтобы этот код работал корректно?

Открывается popup окно --> запускается скрипт, который копирует заголовок окна в поле типа dynamichidden или хотя бы в textarea (которое будет скрыто через CSS), и если пользователь откроет другое popup окно, чтобы скрипт повторился.

Пример selector-а заголовка:
`#\39 6808861 > div > div.eae-modal-title.mfp-title`

Питался гуглить в сторону «как переинициализировать js скрипт» но так ничего и не удалось сделать.

Буду рад любым подсказкам. Большое спасибо!

UPD:
Возможно, проблема в том, что все popup окна загружаются вместе со страницей и код исполняется только один раз еще до открытия popup окна пользователем.

Подскажите, что нужно найти и изменить в коде плагина, чтобы popup окна, загружались исключительно после нажатия кнопки, а не во время загрузки страницы, так как в настройках подобных параметров я не нашел.

Может кому пригодиться идея:
Как вариант можно попробовать использовать другой плагин для popup окон (например Popup Maker), в котором создать много окон с различными заголовками, которые будут открываться после клика по кнопках с определенными CSS классами, но в моем случаи это плохой вариант, так как страница будет регулярно обновляться и нужно, чтобы менеджера могли самостоятельно вписать нужный заголовок прямо во время редактирования страницы в Elementor.

UPD2:
Пытался использовать другие аддоны для Elementor в которых есть popup окна, но везде одна и та же проблема: в первом popup окне на странице заголовок копируется в Contact Form 7, а в остальных – нет.